# Customize style of a vector layer ol3

Tags: openlayers-3

I use a geojson file to build the layer added to a map. What I want is to customize style of the layer's polygons in order to have hatched polygons such as we can do that with mapserver symbols. Is it possible to do this with ol3? I tried to create an image and use it but it only works for point geometry. Thank you for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill patterns for polygons are not (yet) supported in OpenLayers 3, see also https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2208

Comment: Thank you very much, I m gonna find another way to style my polygons.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by now. The `ol.style.Style` object accepts a `CanvasRenderingContext2D` instance, where you can apply an image pattern to your polygons.

**Example Code Snippet**

```
var geojsonObject = 'someGeoJSON' 
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
 features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: source
});

var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png';
img.onload = function() {
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  layer.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: pattern
   })
 }));
};
```

A full example can be seen here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmarquar/toh7tw7h/14/)